# How to enter into the folder given as a command line argument in python

Tags: python, subprocess, file-handling

I want to open the folder that is given as a command-line argument in a python file-like **test.py folder1** and then print all file names in that folder. Also, test.py and folder1 is not in the same directory.

I am stuck in part where I need to enter into the folder that is passed as an arg.

```
import os

filename = sys.srgv[1]
os.chdir("/home/all_folder")
folder= os.listdir()
if filename in folder:
   ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the folder as an argument to os.listdir, then you do not have to use os.chdir to change the curent directory. Below is an example program which takes the folder as the first command line argument, and prints the files in that folder:

```
import os
import sys

folder = sys.argv[1]

folder_content = os.listdir(folder)
for filename in folder_content:
    print(filename)
```

Example usage: `python test.py /home/my_username/somefolder`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path

```py
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

mypath = "C:/Users/fullpath"

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

print(onlyfiles)
```